# Duplicate annotation for class: interface org.testng.annotations. BeforeMethod

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am new to Selenium Java. Upon running the java class it is showing the below error :

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
>   java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for
>   class: interface org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod:
>   @org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod(inheritGroups=true,
>   dependsOnGroups=[], dependsOnMethods=[], firstTimeOnly=false,
>   groups=[], description=, alwaysRun=false,

What does `Duplicate annotation` mean and where excatly should i debug?

**Env** : Eclipse Neon, Mac, Maven project, TestNg framework.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out.
In one of the 'test base class' I bymistake printed

@BeforeMethod tag twice, hence upon running the java class it was showing the above error mentioned.
Removing extra @BeforeMethod tag, resolved this issue.